# query not duplicate tablespace and datafile

Tags: sql

I have tablespaces with more datafile

If i run this query:

```
select distinct table space_name, file_name
from dba_data_files
order by tablespace_name, file_name ASC;
```

it show me for example

```
tablespace a           datafile1
tablespace a           datafile2
tablespace a           datafile3
tablespace b           datafile4
```

I want a result as

```
tablespace a            datafile 1
                        datafile 2
                        datafile 3
tabelspace b            datafile 4
```

How i can do this with a query???

Comment: You *can*; however, you *shouldn't*.  It is usually better and simpler to do such formatting at the application level.

Comment: Yes I know but i need the query to show that result

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this purpose:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by table_space_name order by file_name) = 1
             then table_space_name
        end) as table_space_name,
       file_name 
from dba_data_files
group by table_space_name, file_name
order by tablespace_name, file_name;
```

It is important that the two `order by` clauses be the same.